# Would you consider a text editor such as vi a system program or an application program? Justify.

Tags: operating-system

How i Can identify The Vi Editor is a Application Software or System Software

Answer (score 1):

[System software and Application software](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MoZ5g.jpg)

Software is basically classified into two categories.
**System Software and Application Software.**

Where System Software acts as an interface between Application Software and hardware of the computer. The Application Software acts an interface between user and System Software. We can distinguish System Software and Application Software on account of the purpose of their design. The System Software is designed to manage the system resources and it also provides a platform for Application Software to run. On the other hand Application Software are designed for the users to perform their specific tasks.

So vi is editor created for UNIX Operating System. It is type of Application Software.

Answer (score 0):

Priyank has nicely clarified the difference. But I would like to add a small point here if you have a confusion in deciding the type. Many softwares have both the features; interaction with hardware(system software style) and interaction with the user(application software style). There is a simple way to distinguish between the two: the more it interacts with the hardware and the more it focuses on extending hardware functionality or system services, that are used by other programs, the more it fits into the system software category. In my opinion Text editor is more of an application type software.